Child is overflowing when using grid view in flutter
I wrapped a container with a gridView, as a  result the card is overflowing. i wrapped gridView with a sizeBox and set the height to 600. Can somebody help me with this. im just started learning flutter.

 SizedBox(
                height: 600,
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: List.generate(
                    2,
                    (index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (builder) =>
                                  const ScreenProductDetails(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(8),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                const Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite_outline,
                                    color: Color(0xFF868889),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Image.asset(
                                  'assets/product-images/peach.png',
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 8.0,
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "\$ 7.00",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: Color(0xFF6CC51D),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "Fresh Peach",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const Text(
                                  "Dozen",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: Color(0xFF868889),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 8.0,
                                ),
                                const Divider(
                                  color: Color(0xFFEBEBEB),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (builder) =>
                                            const ScreenCart(),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: const Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                                        size: 15,
                                        color: Color(0xFF6CC51D),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 8.0,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Add to cart",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),


Why GridView if there are only two static children?

It looks like you're encountering an overflow error because the Image.asset widget inside your grid cells doesn't fit within the allotted space, especially when screen sizes or resolutions change.
To solve this problem, you can make the following adjustments:
Wrap the Image.asset with an Expanded widget:

This allows the image to expand to fill the space available in the grid cell without causing overflow.

Set the fit property to BoxFit.contain:

This ensures that the entire image is visible and scales down to fit within its container if necessary.

Here's how you can adjust your code:
Expanded(
  child: Image.asset(
    'assets/product-images/peach.png',
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
),


I tried this It's working but the image is too small i can't even see it. i want that image with its actual size. (the original size of the image is perfect)
